# Express, mongoose display MongoDB values into a div

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Just starting with mongoDB and mongoose, I have a database called "Twitter" with a collection called userPost.
I have my server.js with the connection to the database and the server setup. And the pages.js file in the router folder, which routes every page.

I want the db data to be displayed into a div called "Test".

```
router.get('/', function(req, res) {
res.render('index.ejs', {
 });
});
```

This is my homepage route code, I know after the { I should put something like id_of_div:database_value.
But I'm having some problem in doing that so a helpfull hand would be appreciated. Thanks!

I've created a model schema:

```
let mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var postSchema = new Schema({
    username: { 
        type: String,
        required: true 
    },
    content: { 
        type: String,
        required: true 
    },
});

let userPost = module.exports = mongoose.model('userPost', postSchema);
```

But I don't know how to proceed.

```
<div id="posts">
</div>
```

This is my div in the index.ejs file under a form.

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is import your module Schema in your router module and render it.
Your Routes and app module files will look something like this below

```
***userRoutes.js***

var express = require('express');
var userPostModel = require('./userPostModel');

const userRouter = express.Router();

function router() {
    userRouter.route('/').get((req, res, next) => {
        userPostModel.find({})
            .then(function (userDetails) {
                res.render('index', {
                    userDetails
                });
            }, function (err) {
                next(err);
            });
        next();
    }); 

    return userRouter;
}

module.exports = router;
```

Following is the sample app.js file

```
***app.js***

var express = require('express');
var userRoutes = require('./userRoutes');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

const app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

app.use('/user', userRoutes());
app.set('views', './src/views');
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

app.listen(3000, function() {
    console.log("Listening to port");
})
```

Following is the way you could use it in html file

```
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>
            <h1><%userDetails.username%></h1>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```